# Soundcloud connector to Google Data Studio

Tags: soundcloud, looker-studio

I would like to display the statistics of Soundcloud more clearly. An import to Google Data Studio would be very helpful. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SoundCloud has an API, this can be done through [creating a community-connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/). There are no plans to add a first-party connector to SoundCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answer. I would like to create a community-connector with the Soundcloud API. The Problem is that I cant' create a SoundCloud Application Registration because of the following notice:

SoundCloud Application Registration
Due to the high amount of requests recently received, we will no longer be processing API application requests at this time. We are working to re-evaluate our process to make it more efficient.

Do you know when the registration is available?